# Search on the different page webapp

Tags: forms, web-applications, search, web

I have three simple html or php file that I'm going to create.

What will be include in there is that a content such as video's name or let say a person name

in total it will be almost 2000 of them

but I will split it to three different pages or maybe I will make it one page with different categories.

now my question is that how will I make a search form that can be search from a different page while they are still on the page index

this is what I'm currently using `<div class="searchbox"><form action="index.php" method="post"> <input type="text" name="q" value="">`

this search form is a live time search result

but I will it to be able to search from other page as well or from a different categories

but where should I put the tag or anything to the content in order to get the search show the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like that could be done with javascript but it isn't really my forte.  But one issue with this is the other pages don't really exist on the users browser until they have browsed them so you might have to download a bunch of pages in the background.  Doesn't sound like a great solution to me.

I'd recommend doing searches on the server side where you have the data, rather than trying to parse rendered html on the users machine.  And then send the results to the user.

Comment: so basically I should have it like Wordpress post where the data being post to the database and they will request it where there do the search

but then it bring another problem on the huge server usages because a thousand of people will do the search am I correct?

Comment: 1000 is not huge, but I guess it depends on your perspective.  If you're going to have lots of users you need the necessary hardware.  I don't know how Wordpress works.

Comment: well I heard wordpress is using a lots of memory for each search and visits

I use to have like 10000 members and there was no search engine just login to check session and stuff to access to my members area and the memory I have was 2GB and my website always down